# Изменение пути файлов Grunt, Usemin

Tags: node.js, jade, grunt

Grunt + Jade file:

```js
jadeUsemin: {
  scripts: {
    options: {
      tasks: {
        js: ['concat', 'uglify'],
        css: ['concat', 'cssmin']
      }
    },
    files: [{
      dest: 'server/views/compiled/css.jade',
      src: 'server/views/compiled/css.jade'
    }, {
      dest: 'server/views/compiled/scripts.jade',
      src: 'server/views/compiled/scripts.jade'
    }]
  }
}
```

```css
//-<!-- build:js(app) dist/bower.min.js -->
// bower:js
link(rel='stylesheet', href='bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.core.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='bower_components/pnotify/pnotify.buttons.css')
// endbower
//-<!-- endbuild -->
```

Все работает, но создается новый файлик с скриптами:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='dist/bower.min.js')
```

У меня папка dist - корневая, и потому мне нужна ссылка

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='bower.min.js')
```

Если изменить блок *build:js(app) dist/bower.min.js* на *build:js(app) bower.min.js* - то ссылка становиться правильной, но файл не помещаэтся в нужную папку: "dist", а создается в корневой сервера.

**Вопрос**

Как можно изменить адреса файлов чтоб убрать папку "dist". Можно это сделать средствами jadeUsemin?

Я работаю с jade фалами. Перейти на html не могу!

Спасибо!!!

Comment: Попробуйте поиграть с опцией `replacePath` jadeUsemin. Возможно, поможет